# Solve Equations Like (3 + 7) + 2 * 8 / 2 That Are Entered in a textarea

Tags: javascript

Any basic addition, subtraction, multiplication and division equation can be entered in the console or set to a variable:

```
var solve = (3 + 7) + 2 * 8 / 2 // 18
```

and correctly solved.

My code is not doing this. I believe it has something to do with the textarea. When I enter (3 + 7) + 2 * 8 / 2 it displays (3 + 7) + 2 * 8 / 2 (instead of 18). Note that my code doesn't have a solve button, it solves as the problem is entered.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kt4SL/

HTML

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="pSolve"></textarea>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var input = document.getElementById("pSolve");

input.onkeyup = function() {
    // Solve the input
    finalAnswer = pSolve.value;

    // Display answer
    answer.innerHTML = finalAnswer;
}
```

I tried this:

```
// Solve the input
finalAnswer = Number(pSolve.value);
```

thinking it would fix it but it didn't work. Instead nothing was displayed. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the easiest thing for you to use is `eval`. It's not necessarily the best solution, though.

Comment: This is a fun little parsing/shunting project to do - but it's already been done alot before too (and I am sure there are duplicates). This is usually given as a programming assignment to undergrads.

Comment: @Gabe `eval` is the perfect solution. Especially when you're the one providing the input.

Comment: @Bart: `eval` is great if your input language exactly matches JS expressions. If any part of your syntax doesn't perfectly match JS, though, you can't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `eval` to evaluate the equation.

```
answer.innerHTML = eval(finalAnswer);
```

[I updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt4SL/1/)

---

[Have a look at this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459798/javascript-regular-expression-to-parse-a-formula/18472163#18472163). The question was about parsing a formula but it's pretty much usable for anything really.

Answer (score 1):

You are just extracting a String from the text area and pasting it into the answer div. Strings are not just evaluated by javascript! What you are actually doing is `var solve = '(3 + 7) + 2 * 8 / 2';`! You would need a parser to actually solve that problem, like in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052470/javascript-parser-for-simple-expression).

Answer (score 1):

You can do repeated replacement to evaluate arithmetic expressions thus:

```
function performOp(_, a, op, b) {
  switch (op) {
    case '+': return +a + +b;
    case '-': return +a - +b;
    case '*': return +a * +b;
    case '/': return +a / +b;
  }
}

function evaluateArithmetic(expr) {
  expr = expr.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  while (true) {
    var oldExprPS = expr;
    while (true) {
      var oldExprDM = expr;
      expr = expr.replace(/\((-?\d+)\)/g, '$1');
      expr = expr.replace(/(-?\d+)([*\/])(-?\d+)/g, performOp);
      expr = expr.replace(/\((-?\d+)([+\-])(-?\d+)\)/g, performOp);
      if (expr == oldExprDM) { break; }
    }
    expr = expr.replace(/(-?\d+)([+\-])(-?\d+)/g, performOp);
    if (expr == oldExprPS) { break; }
  }
  return +expr;
}

var input = document.getElementById("pSolve");

input.onkeyup = function() {
  // Solve the input
  finalAnswer = evaluateArithmetic(pSolve.value);

  // Display answer
  answer.innerHTML = finalAnswer;
};
```

Comment: Does this actually take parentheses into account?

Comment: No, it doesn't handle parentheses at all. I still like the solution, it's pretty neat for a very simple version of the problem.

Comment: @minitech, My first cut did not, but I believe it does now.  It's basically a simple inside-out parser and tree evaluator so now uses two loops to handle the two levels of operator precedence.

Comment: @ Mike Samuel Thanks for this but why wouldn't I just use eval? It seems so much simpler and works fine for what I'm doing.

Comment: @user1822824, `eval` is overkill for this.  It's way too powerful a tool, and so opens you up to all kinds of security risks like XSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do more than that to solve the equations entered in a text box. Your current script only displays the content of the text box as is. You should use MathJS. It should help.

[MathJS Home](http://mathjs.org)